# how can i convert 1 array or separate its values to multiple array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

how can i convert 1 array or separate its values to multiple array in javascript?

i got an array like this:

```
    const data = 
[
    {
    'Name': 'John'
    'Age': 20
    'Company': 'Google'
    },
    {
    'Name': 'Philip'
    'Age': 21
    'Company': 'Mozzila'
    },
    {
    'Name': 'Matthew'
    'Age': 22
    'Company': 'Microsoft'
    },
    {
    'Name': 'Peter'
    'Age': 23
    'Company': 'Accenture'
    },

]
```

how can i transform that array like this:

```
data = {
 'Data1':['John', 'Philip','Matthew', 'Peter'],
 'Data2':[20,21,22,23]
 'Data3':['Google','Mozzila','Microsoft','Accenture']
}
```

or like this:

```
data = {
 'Name':['John', 'Philip','Matthew', 'Peter'],
 'Age':[20,21,22,23]
 'Company':['Google','Mozzila','Microsoft','Accenture']
}
```

Comment: Those initial objects don't really look valid - the `Name` and `Company` values look to be variables, not strings? Also, have you made any attempt yourself yet?

Comment: i edit the question...

Comment: i'm planning to create an function for each array. so 3 loop..

Comment: `i'm planning to` Please make an attempt *before* posting your question instead of asking SO to do all the work for you - that's not what SO is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [
  {
    'Name': 'John',
    'Age': 20,
    'Company': 'Google'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Philip',
    'Age': 21,
    'Company': 'Mozzila'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Matthew',
    'Age': 22,
    'Company': 'Microsoft'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Peter',
    'Age': 23,
    'Company': 'Accenture'
  },
];

const results = data.reduce((a, e) => {
  for (const key in e) {
    if (!(key in a)) { 
      a[key] = []; 
    }

    a[key].push(e[key]);
  }

  return a;
}, {});

console.log(results);
```

The idea is for each object in `data`, loop over its keys and push each value into an array in the destination object. This might be a little slow, but it works regardless of the names of your keys and is reasonably terse.

Answer (score 1):

Below uses *reduce* to iterate over the `data` array and build an *object* as it does.  This is done dynamically by iterating over each object's keys.

The consistency of your objects are essential. If one object has more keys than another, the array indexes will no longer be kept in sync.

```js
const data = getData();

const obj = data.reduce((obj, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(key => {
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[key]))
      obj[key] = []

    obj[key].push(curr[key])
  })
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(obj);

// Data:
function getData() {
  return [{
      'Name': 'John',
      'Age': 20,
      'Company': 'Google'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Philip',
      'Age': 21,
      'Company': 'Mozzila'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Matthew',
      'Age': 22,
      'Company': 'Microsoft'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Peter',
      'Age': 23,
      'Company': 'Accenture'
    }
  ]
}
```

---

#### Alternative

An alternative is to describe which key to keep.  Notice I've removed some of your key/value pairs from the data structure.  See how the resulting object is kept in sync by inserting an `undefined` in the value's place:

```js
const data = getData(),
  keys = ['Name', 'Age', 'Company'];

const obj = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (!Array.isArray(result[key]))
      result[key] = []

    result[key].push(item[key])
  })
  return result
}, {})

console.log(obj);


// Data:
function getData() {
  return [{
      'Age': 20,
      'Company': 'Google'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Philip',
      'Age': 21
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Matthew',
      'Company': 'Microsoft'
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Peter',
      'Age': 23,
      'Company': 'Accenture'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach ,You can have seperate map for each keys . keeping it simple

```js
const data = 
[
    {
    'Name': 'John',
    'Age': 20,
    'Company': 'Google'
    },
    {
    'Name':'Philip',
    'Age': 21,
    'Company': 'Mozzila'
    },
    {
    'Name':'Matthew',
    'Age': 22,
    'Company': 'Microsoft'
    },
    {
    'Name': 'Peter',
    'Age': 23,
    'Company': 'Accenture'
    },

];
let a={'Name':data.map(d=>d.Name),'Age':data.map(d=>d.Age),'Company':data.map(d=>d.Company)};
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [

    {
        "name" : "xxx",
        "age" : 20,
        "company" : "aaa"
    },
    {
        "name" : "yyy",
        "age" : 30,
        "company" : "bbb"
    },
    {
        "name" : "zzz",
        "age" : 40,
        "company" : "ccc"
    }

];

var newData = {};

for(var x =0 ; x < data.length; x++){
    for(var obj in data[x]){
        if(!newData[obj]){
            newData[obj] = [];
        }
        newData[obj].push( data[x][obj] );
    }
}
console.log(newData);

/* Result */
/* 

{
    name: ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"],
    age: [20, 30, 40], 
    company: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
}

*/
```